# Error getting data from a function and saving on mongodb

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

i have a function that get a expiry date from a mysql server, and save that date with other information on mongodb, 
but after running, everything is saved except the date.

Function:

```
const sql = "SELECT expiry from membri where pass =  '" + license + "'"
           function expiry(license, callback, results){
           con.query(sql, results)
           if (results) {
           callback(results[0].expiry)
           }
           }
```

Save data

```
const newUser = new User({
                            userKey: license,
                            authenicated: true,
                            discordUserID: discordUserID,
                            currentDate: new Date(),
                            expiredDate: new expiry(license)
                              });
                             console.log(new Date())
                          // save user
                           newUser
                            .save()
                            .then(() => {
                              const member = guild.member(msg.author);
                              if (member) {
                                // after successfully authenicated, give user role => access for only 30 days
                                member.addRole(memberRoleID);

                                const successEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                                  .setAuthor("Authentication Bot ( SUCCESS )")
                                  .setColor("#9b42f4")
                                  .addField(
                                    "Activated: ",
                                    `${license} :white_check_mark:`
                                  );

                                return msg.author.send(successEmbed);
                              }
                            })

                             [...]
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The date returned from mysql isnt saved on mongo db